# library installed in site-packages but not in lib folder

Tags: python

I was trying to use urllib library but an error was shown

```
import urllib.request
```

```
Traceback (most recent call last):                                                                                                                                                           
  File "E:\coding\python for everybody\third part\urllib.py", line 1, in <module>                                                                                                            
    import urllib.request                                                                                                                                                                    
  File "E:\coding\python for everybody\third part\urllib.py", line 1, in <module>                                                                                                            
    import urllib.request                                                                                                                                                                    
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'urllib.request'; 'urllib' is not a package                                                                                                             
process is terminated with return code 1.
```

I installed urllib3 using pip but, the package was installed in roaming/python/python39/site-packages.
While the path is set to C:\Program Files\Python\scripts. The folders python39 and python are located in different folders. Also, upon checking I found that package urllib was installed already C:\Program Files\Python\scripts.

I don't know how python is accessing the packages and how it determines the location as none of the packages are being imported (except random and other preinstalled packages).This problem has been very problematic not only this time but many times before.

PS: some time ago I deleted python (6 months approx) and at that time python was installed in roaming is this the result of that?
I am also using anaconda distribution, but the above code was being written in sublime text(Windows 10).

UPDATE: ISSUE WAS SOLVED BY CHANGING THE FILE NAME(LOOK IN THE COMMENTS)

Comment: What is your python filename?

Comment: It seems you have filename like `E:\coding\python for everybody\third part\urllib.py` . So don't use module or package name as a filename.

Comment: @ZalakBhalani Thanks it worked but should the site-packages be in a different directory?

Answer (score 0):

If you are using code editors like VSCode, Notepad+++ and not PyCharm or other python IDE. I think you should check your path and make sure that you have same python version.

Comment: Thanks for suggestion it worked by changing the file name as suggested in the comment above.

Answer (score 0):

Your filename is the same as the library that causes confusion, please change the name as python will get looking at the working directory for import hence the error